# How do I fix Visual code studio's GUI? It is broken, no text

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-code

Out of the blue Visual Code Studio now behaves like below (Ubuntu):

[image: No text / font visible]

That is: no text, but there are only shades of gray and white areas.

How do I fix this? I do not know how did happened (maybe Nuget package manger or Nuget gallery, but earlier it worked ok with these extensions).

Are there any cache dirs that should be emptied or ..?

Comment: @Martheen why do you confidently think that that answers this question? I am not aware of any settings that can cause this behaviour to happen.